# Creating Dynamic XML request body in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and need some help with creating a dynamic Soap message.I am trying to post the below XML body as HTTP request in Jmeter -

```
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://XXXXXsoap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://XXXXX/“>
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
<tem:ProcessMessage>
<tem:message>
            <![CDATA[
                <LoyaltyMessages xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/XXXX/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="hXXXX/XMLSchema" XID="4" YYY="4186" ZZZ="998" PPP="1" LLLL="2" DateTime="2022-09-13T13:30:12" LLL="1">
                    <TransactionRequests>
                        <TransactionRequest Type="0">
                            <Request JJJ="0" SSS="1">
                                <Items>
                                    <Item SeqID="1" ItemCode="1145677" DepCode="105" SaleType="0" QtyType="1" Qty="2" NetPrice="1400" NetAmount="2800"/>
                                    <Item SeqID="2" ItemCode="1145677" DepCode="105" SaleType="0" QtyType="1" Qty="2" NetPrice="1400" NetAmount="2800"/>

                                </Items>
                                <Total TotalAmount="28.00" TotalNumberOfItems="2"/>
                            </Request>
                        </TransactionRequest>
                    </TransactionRequests>
                </LoyaltyMessages>
            ]]> 
</tem:message>
</tem:ProcessMessage>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to substitute the tags within Items field with a dynamic body that can have upto 50-100 items with incrementing SeqID so it looks like -

```
<Items>
       <Item SeqID="1" ItemCode="${ItemCode}" DepCode="${DepCode}" SaleType="${SaleType}" QtyType="${QtyType}" Qty="${Qty}" NetPrice="${NetPrice}" NetAmount="${NetAmount}"/>
                                    <Item SeqID="2" ItemCode="${ItemCode}" DepCode="${DepCode}" SaleType="${SaleType}" QtyType="${QtyType}" Qty="${Qty}" NetPrice="${NetPrice}" NetAmount="${NetAmount}"/>
                                    <Item SeqID="3" ItemCode="${ItemCode}" DepCode="${DepCode}" SaleType="${SaleType}" QtyType="${QtyType}" Qty="${Qty}" NetPrice="${NetPrice}" NetAmount="${NetAmount}"/>

                                </Items>
```

I am using a CSV dataset config but it adds the same values for all item list as it is the same request. Also not sure how to achieve multiple tag blocks inside Items tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate dynamic block of `Items` using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like:

1. Change your request body to:

   ```
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://XXXXXsoap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://XXXXX/">
       <soap:Header/>
       <soap:Body>
           <tem:ProcessMessage>
               <tem:message>
                   <![CDATA[
                   <LoyaltyMessages xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/XXXX/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="hXXXX/XMLSchema" XID="4" YYY="4186" ZZZ="998" PPP="1" LLLL="2" DateTime="2022-09-13T13:30:12" LLL="1">
                       <TransactionRequests>
                           <TransactionRequest Type="0">
                               <Request JJJ="0" SSS="1">
                                   <Items>
                                   ${items}
                                   </Items>
                                   <Total TotalAmount="28.00" TotalNumberOfItems="${numberOfItems}"/>
                               </Request>
                           </TransactionRequest>
                       </TransactionRequests>
                   </LoyaltyMessages>
               ]]>
               </tem:message>
           </tem:ProcessMessage>
       </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>
   ```
2. Add JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of the HTTP Request sampler and put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   def numberOfItems = 10

   def items = new StringBuilder()

   1.upto(numberOfItems, { index ->
       items.append('<Item SeqID="')
               .append(index)
               .append('" ItemCode="')
               .append(vars.get('ItemCode'))
               .append('"')
               .append('"')
               .append(' DepCode="')
               .append(vars.get('DepCode'))
               .append('" SaleType="')
               .append(vars.get('SaleType'))
               .append('" QtyType="')
               .append(vars.get('QtyType'))
               .append(" Qty=")
               .append(vars.get('Qty'))
               .append('" NetPrice="')
               .append(vars.get('NetPrice'))
               .append('" NetAmount="')
               .append(vars.get('NetAmount'))
               .append('"/>')
               .append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
   })

   vars.put('items', items.toString())
   vars.put('numberOfItems', numberOfItems as String)
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri , I used a similar approach but the problem with this is, while using a csv dataset config it just uses the same data for all the items instead of picking up new row of data from the csv - <Items>
                                  <Item SeqID="1" ItemCode="69085"" DepCode="110" SaleType="0" QtyType="1 Qty=1" NetPrice="100" NetAmount="100"/>
<Item SeqID="2" ItemCode="69085"" DepCode="110" SaleType="0" QtyType="1 Qty=1" NetPrice="100" NetAmount="100"/>
<Item SeqID="3" ItemCode="69085"" DepCode="110" SaleType="0" QtyType="1 Qty=1" NetPrice="100" NetAmount="100"/>
 </Items>